# AngularJS: Alterar escopo em ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Tenho a situação: na tabela abaixo, quando eu clico em "editar", exibe o form com os campos necessários (inclusive com um novo botão de "cancelar"). Até aqui está tudo funcionando bem. O problema é que ao salvar, o form deveria desaparecer (ng-hide) e voltar a apresentar os dados normais. Logo abaixo tem um trecho com o JS. Ao que entendi não estou conseguindo mudar a "editing" depois de salvar.

**Tabela com telefones**

```
<form name="telefoneEdit">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="30%">Telefone</th>
                <th width="20%">Ramal</th>
                <th width="40%">Descrição</th>
                <th width="10%"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="telefone in clienteCtrl.cliente.ClienteTelefone" ng-form="tel" ng-init="editing = false">
            <tr ng-show="!editing">
                <td>{{telefone.tel}}</td>
                <td>{{telefone.ramal}}</td>
                <td>{{telefone.descricao}}</td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <a ng-click="editing = true" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="icon-pencil2"></i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-show="editing">
                <td>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input ng-model="telefone.ddd" type="number" name="ddd" max="99" ng-maxlength="2" class="form-control input-sm"></input>
                        <label class="error" ng-show="tel.ddd.$invalid">Campo inválido</label>
                        <label class="error" ng-show="erros.ddd">{{erros.ddd[0]}}</label>   
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="number" name="telefone" ng-model="telefone.telefone" class="form-control input-sm" ng-minlength="8" required></input>
                        <label class="error" ng-show="tel.telefone.$invalid">Campo inválido</label> 
                    </div>                                  
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input ng-model="telefone.ramal" class="form-control input-sm"></input>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input ng-model="telefone.descricao" class="form-control input-sm"></input>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="button" ng-click="editTelefone(telefone)"><i class="icon-disk"></i></button>
                    <a ng-click="editing = false" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="icon-close"></i></a>
                </td>
                <input type="hidden" ng-model="telefone.id" />
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

**Trecho do JS que deveria funcionar**

```
$scope.editTelefone = function(telefone) {            
    var erros = {};
    var _data = {};
    _data.ClienteTelefone = telefone;
    self.editing = false;
    $http
        .post('api/cliente_telefones/edit.json',_data)
        .success(function(data){
            if(data.erros) {
                $scope.erros = data.erros;
            } 
            else {
                self.telefone = telefone;
                $scope.erros = false;
                $scope.editing = false;
            }
        })
}
```

Tudo funciona corretamente, só não consigo esconder o form novamente.

**Imagens ilustrativas**

[image: Tabela em seu estado original/inicial]
Tabela em seu estado original/inicial

[image: Form de edição]
Form de edição

[image: Resultado após submeter o form de edição]
Resultado após submeter o form de edição

Comment: Você colocou a tag de `angularjs-directives`, esse código JS que você postou está dentro de um directive? ou de um controller?

Comment: Está em um controller

Comment: Você conseguiu verificar se está tendo algum retorno dentro do `success`? Se o resultado que você espera realmente está chegando?

Comment: @CelsomTrindade está tudo funcionando corretamente: os dados são enviados e salvos no banco sem problemas. Mas o $scope.editing = false não está refletindo nenhum efeito. Este é o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um ponto a ser observado é o uso do `self`. Posso estar enganado, mas pelo que sei, no controller nós usamos `this` ou, mais comumente utilizado através da syntax `vm` deste modo:

```
var vm = this;
```

Mas seria necessário mudar a syntax de definição do `controller` no DOM para `controller as vm` e todos os valores de `scope` deveriam possuir o prefixo `vm.` ex.: `ng-show="vm.editing"`. Como não é o seu caso, recomendo que não utilize a referencia de `self` e utilize diretamente `$scope`.

Outra observação a ser feita, é sobre a definição do `ng-repeat`. Você declarou diretamente na tag `tbody`, o que não é o aconselhável. Como você precisa repetir 2 blocos de `tr` você deve utilizar uma opção do `ng-repeat` que, inclusive, é muito pouco usado/comentado, que seria:

```
ng-repeat-start="item in items"
&
ng-repeat-end
```

No seu caso, deve ser usado assim:

```
<tr ng-show="!editing" ng-repeat-start="telefone in clienteCtrl.cliente.ClienteTelefone">
    //.. restante do primeiro bloco de código
</tr>
<tr ng-show="editing" ng-repeat-end>
    //.. restante do bloco de edição
</tr>
```

Quanto ao problema em si de esconder o formulário após a edição, o problema acontece por que a variável `$scope.editing` está definida dentro do ng-repeat, ou seja, para cada bloco que repetir, sempre vai existir essa variável, então ele irá habilitar/desabilitar todos de uma única vez.

Uma solução que usei quando tive um problema semelhante foi de criar um novo campo dentro da array e controlar a exibição a partir desse campo, deixando sua array assim por exemplo:

```
$scope.telefones = [
    {id:1, visible: false, telefone: '(48)99665588'},
    //..mais objetos
]
```

E dentro do `controller`, controlaríamos a exibição de acordo com o campo "visible", assim somente o objeto desejado estará apto para edição.

```
$scope.mostraEdit = function(id) {
  $filter('filter')($scope.telefones, {id: id})[0].visible = true;
};
$scope.escondeEdit = function(id) {
  $filter('filter')($scope.telefones, {id: id})[0].visible = false;
};
$scope.salvaTelefone = function(data) {
  $filter('filter')($scope.telefones, {id: data.id})[0].visible = false;
};
```

E no DOM teríamos isso:

```
<tr ng-show="!telefone.visible" ng-repeat-start="telefone in telefones" ng-form="tel">
  //.. listagem de telefones
</tr>
<tr ng-show="telefone.visible" ng-repeat-end>
    //.. formulario de edição
</tr>
```

Comment: Excelentes observações. Vou testar e informo o resultado. Quanto ao self, ele está definido anteriormente no código como um var self = this

Comment: Certo. Então não tem problema utilizar a definição de `self` mas lembre-se, ele não vai funcionar a não ser que você mude toda a syntax do seu código. Neste caso, recomendo não utilizar como `self` pois você está utilizando a referencia de `$scope` no DOM e Controller. Ou mude tudo para syntax as, como comentei, ou mude para `$scope.variavel`

Comment: estive aplicando suas sugestões. A questão do 'ng-repeat' ficou perfeita. Mas o grande problema, que é esconder o form quando a resposta está correta, ou seja, setando '$scope.editing = false' continua sem funcionar. Vou adicionar na postagem imagens exemplificando o caso.

Comment: Você já substituiu o uso do `self` dentro do `editTelefone()` ?

Comment: Sim, já tinha feito isso antes.

Comment: Estranho.. no exemplo simplificado que criei com o seu código (ou seja, sem o http) funcionou tudo certo.. Tente deixar a função do `editTelefone` somente com o `$scope.editing = false;` e veja o que acontece.

Comment: Comentei tudo, deixei apenas `.success(function(data){ $scope.editing = false; }` e ainda assim não funciona...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33914/discussion-between-celsomtrindade-and-danilo-miguel).